# focusing on an element after an event is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to display an alert message if the user does not select any item in the dropdown then focus that dropdown. I want to do this in all dropdowns with the class "select".

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {    
    if (!$(".select").val()) {
        alert("please select one");
        event.preventDefault();
    $(".select").focus();
    }
});
```

Now, this works fine for one dropdown, but when there are multiple dropdowns, it focuses on the very last, not the particular dropdown.For example, consider an html page with three dropdowns.

```
<select class="select" id="usertype">
<option value="">Select one</option>
<option value="guest">Guest</option>
<option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>

<select class="select" id="gender">
<option value="">Select one</option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>

<select class="select" id="languages">
<option value="">Select one</option>
<option value="c++">c++</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

If I selected some items in both languages and gender but select nothing from usertype ("Select one"'s value is ""), the alert message is displayed, but the focus goes to languages, instead of usertype.

What should I do to focus on the unselect dropdown (or the first unselected if the user did not choose items from many dropdowns)?

Comment: Presumably you want to focus on the first `.select` element without an entered value? Can you share a representative ([MCVE]) sample of your HTML with which this jQuery is supposed to work?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, why our answers are getting downvoted and the above *worthless* comment is getting upvoted.

Comment: I'd be interested if the people down-voting could offer some insight as to how the proposed answers are "not useful," that way the authors - and those of us reading the answers - might learn something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `$.each`,

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
    $(".select").each(function(){
        if (!$(this).val()) {
          alert("please select one");
          event.preventDefault();
          $(this).focus();
          return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing - and these are not my down-votes - that it has to do with the lack of explanation of how the code in this answer works to solve the problem, but I'm genuinely not sure.

Comment: Ah, I haven't look at this answer before. I actually found out my jquery code doesn't really check all dropdown because I didn't use .each. But this is exactly what I want to do before I edited my question!

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {    
    if (!$(".select").val()) {
        alert("please select one");
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".select[selectedIndex=0]").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd be grateful if whoever down voted my answer could explain why, I believe it perfectly answers the question in as simple way as is possible.

Comment: @morbidCode Thanks for the HTML, my answer should work.

Comment: @Praveen: while you're absolutely correct, I don't think Zak can look yet (not until he gets 10k reputation).

Comment: @DavidThomas Right! Agreed.

Comment: I have edited and upvoted to nullify your downvote. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Given the updated HTML, and in the face of some rampant unexplained down-voting, I'd suggest the following:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the 'click'
// method as the event-handler for clicks on the
// element with the id of 'submit':
$("#submit").click(function (event) {

    // caching all the elements with the class of
    // 'select':
    var selects = $('.select'),

    // filtering those cached elements elements,
    // retaining only those for whom the assessment
    // provided to filter()'s anonymous function
    // returns a value of true, or is 'truthy':
        hasNoValue = selects.filter(function () {

            // here we're checking that the current
            // select has a value of '' (empty string):
            return this.value === '' && 

            // and that its currently selected <option>
            // (this.options is a collection of the
            // <option> elements within the current
            // <select> element, and this.selectedIndex
            // is the index of the selected <option>
            // in the options collection) has the
            // text of 'Select one'
            // (String.prototype.trim() removes leading
            // and trailing white-space from a supplied
            // string):
            this.options[this.selectedIndex].text.trim() === 'Select one'
        });

    // if the hasNoValue collection of <select> elements has a length
    // other than (the 'falsey') 0, then we enter the 'if':
    if (hasNoValue.length) {

        // preventing the default action of the click event:
        event.preventDefault();

        // selecting the first element from the collection
        // held within hasNoValue, and focusing that one:
        hasNoValue.eq(0).focus();
    }
});
```

```js
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
  var selects = $('.select'),
    hasNoValue = selects.filter(function() {
      return this.value === '' && this.options[this.selectedIndex].text.trim() === 'Select one'
    });
  if (hasNoValue.length) {
    hasNoValue.eq(0).focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" id="usertype">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="guest">Guest</option>
  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
</select>
<select class="select" id="gender">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<select class="select" id="languages">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="c++">c++</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
<button id="submit">submit button</button>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q4ker359/), for experimentation and development.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
  - [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).